# correct this xpath expression please

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, contains, xpath

This is a piece of my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<mfVictor>
 <decal>
    <company>Victor</company>
    <title>Wood Horn with Blue Background</title>
    <image>
      <url>victor01.jpg</url>
      <width>60</width>
      <height>60</height>
      <name>Wood Horn Blue Background</name>
      <link></link>
    </image>
    <price>$15.00</price>
    <instock>In Stock</instock>
    <notes>none</notes>
  </decal>
</mfVictor>
</catalog>
```

I have a function that generates a list of the text from each "title" element.  So then, onmousedown of each list item I want to navigate to the "decal" and access all of its children.  So far I have this:

```
//decal[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]
```

where the itemName is this.innerHTML passed to the function.  It looks like the decal is accessed because in the console.log I can see an XMLobject with a length of 1.  But I can't figure out how to access either the children of "decal" or the siblings of "title".

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select a decal based on his title I would prefer the following xpaths:

```
//decal/title[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]/parent::node()
//decal/title[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]/..
//decal[title[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]]
```

to select a sibling of the title of the decal you selected you can use

```
//decal/title[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]/following-sibling::*
```

If you want all the children of the decal you select you can use (maybe you need this)

```
//decal[title[contains(.,\'"+itemName+"\')]]/child::*
```

or better, if you have the complete title

```
//decal[title[text()=\'"+itemName+"\']]/child::*
```

With the square bracket you instruct the parser to walk the xml tree to make a selection based on the condition you specify but without changing the context node. Think to the square brackets as a rubber-band, once the test contained in it are satisfied the parser revert back to the starting node and evaluate the rest of the xpath expression. The first two examples are a tipical

Comment: That explains it.  I needed the last one of your examples.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want //decal[contains(./Title, 'Wood Horn with Blue Background')]

This should give you the decal node with a child node named 'Title' that contains the text 'Wood Horn with Blue Background'

To access the siblings of the Title element you would select the *children* of the node that this returns.  (It's actually returning the decal node, not the title node.)